# Dynamically added views not displaying in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

The client I am building for needs a feature that requires me wrap a scroll view around a lot of content, including the 'news' section. Because of this, I can't use a ListView. I am attempting to manually inflate all of the ListItem views into a vertical LinearLayout. I realize I'll lose of the sweet optimizations of ListView, but it's what the client wants so I have to oblige. I feel like my solution should be working, but no views are being drawn to the screen. Inside of my ScrollView is a LinearLayout, and inside of it is this second LinearLayout:

```
<!-- News Fragment -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/news_frag"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@color/test_yellow"/>
```

Here is the layout file for NewsListItem:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingTop="5dp"
android:paddingBottom="5dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:onClick="newsListItemClick"
android:background="@color/test_green">

<com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
    style="@style/thumbnail_image"
    android:id="@+id/news_list_item_image"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/thumbnail_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/thumbnail_height" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView 
        style="@style/headline_text"
        android:id="@+id/news_list_item_headline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView 
        style="@style/promo_text"
        android:id="@+id/news_list_item_promo_brief"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And finally, the code I'm using programmatically. newsRequest() is the last call I make in onCreateView:

```
private void newsRequest() {
    Log.d("snw", "newsRequest()");
    JsonArrayRequest jsonRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(NEWS_FEED_URL, 
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    NewsListItem item = new NewsListItem((JSONObject) response.get(i));
                    View view = addNewsToView(item);
                    containerView.addView(view);
                    containerView.invalidate();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            containerView.bringToFront(); //something I tried, didn't help
            containerView.postInvalidate(); //Same as above
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }

    });

    volleyQueue.add(jsonRequest);
}

private View addNewsToView(NewsListItem item) {
    Log.d("snw", "addNewsToView()");
    ViewHolder holder;
    View view = new View(getActivity());

    if (view.getTag() == null) {
        Log.d("snw", "Holder was null, inflating view");
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_list_item, null);

        // set up ViewHolder
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.thumbnail = (NetworkImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.news_list_item_image);
        holder.headline = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.news_list_item_headline);
        holder.promoBrief = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.news_list_item_promo_brief);

        //set custom fonts
        Typeface futuraBold =
                Typeface.createFromAsset(view.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/futura_today_bold.ttf");
        Typeface futuraLight =
                Typeface.createFromAsset(view.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/futura_today_light.ttf");

        holder.headline.setTypeface(futuraBold);
        holder.promoBrief.setTypeface(futuraLight);

        // store holder with the view
        view.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    holder.headline.setText(item.getHeadline());
    holder.promoBrief.setText(item.getPromoBrief());
    holder.thumbnail.setImageUrl(UrlBuilder.buildUrl(item.getImgUrl()),
            VolleySingleton.getInstance(getActivity()).getImageLoader());


    return view;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    NetworkImageView thumbnail;
    TextView headline;
    TextView promoBrief;
}
```

Everything I've read suggests this should be working fine, it's just as easy as calling addView and attaching my inflated view to the ViewGroup container, a LinearLayout. A few things I've read suggesting manually setting the LayoutParameters on the view before attaching it, but this had no effect as far as I can tell. Any insight?

Comment: Did you get solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I got an Idea for using the ListView even if you have to scroll content above and beneath with it. You can define a footer and a header to an ListView, this makes it appear above and below just as you would expect. For me that looked like this:

```
View headerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_header_layout, null, false);
this.footer = new MyFooterView(getActivity());
this.interactionsList.addHeaderView(headerView);
this.interactionsList.addFooterView(this.footer);
```

Works like a charm. :)

I found an example, notice the Elements above and below, which behave as they would within the ListView: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pAiHQAE5G6c